# How to access on-premisses servers from Microsoft hosted agents virtual machine?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am build the our application on Microsoft hosted agent and sonarqube scanner is hosted on our local machine.
The main issue is Microsoft hosted agent is not connect to our local machine and sonarqube scanner task is failed.

I want to know that how to communicate with local machine from Microsoft hosted agent virtual machine?

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable the networking for the on-prem vm. Since by default it doesn't allow the access.

[image]

[image]

Now in azure devops you would need to go to Project Settings, then Service connections, and if you have the sonarqube VSTS extension properly added from the market place you will be able to see the SonarQube option in the New service connection

[image]

[Document Reference](https://somakdas.medium.com/sonarqube-integration-with-azure-devops-a9ccd6d23fc9)

Comment: Thanks! But due to security reason I can not open the any port for any source. So any another way to solve this issue.

Comment: @AnilKumarGupta Since sonarqube deployed on your vm on particular and to access that from outside you have to open that. You can provide security by putting in secure virtual network

Comment: can I use Microsoft App Proxy for that? Have you any idea or documents links for that?

Comment: Actually there are two things in there fist is sonatqube and second is twistlock and both are hosted in our on-premisses servers and I want to implement both in our pipeline.